# R integrate function error (simple syntax error I can't find) (Error in integrate(f, a, b) : length(lower) == 1 is not TRUE)

Tags: r, function, compiler-errors, numerical-integration

I have a function whose value is the integral of another well-established function. Then I want to create a new function whose value is the integral of the function, whose value is the integral :) The first step is OK, but then the second gives a error. Here's the code:

> A <- 1
>
> f <- function(a) a^2
>
> g <- function(a,b) integrate(f,a,b)$value
>
> h <- function(s) g(s,A)
>
> integrate(h,0,A)

The error I get is:

> Error in integrate(f, a, b) : length(lower) == 1 is not TRUE

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

1. I tried to Google and did not find this specific situation.
2. I also tried to actually integrate g to obtain h, numerically ad hoc: take dx>0, then dx*sum(sapply(seq(a,b,by=dx),h)) just to obtain a number, but I would like to do it with an integrated function.

Comment: Could you please also provide the exact error message?

Comment: Sure. I added in the message body now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `integrate`  will not accept an array of values for the lower bound, only a single number. That means your function `h(s)` cannot accept a vector of values.  But `integrate` also requires that the function to be integrated is vectorized. You can fix this with the function `Vectorize`.
If you change the definition of h, your code will work.

```
h <- Vectorize(function(s) g(s,A))
integrate(h,0,A)
0.25 with absolute error < 2.8e-15
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a question. I am not requiring that h accepts an array of values, am I? Why does then f work, but not h? I see no difference between them. That's what really confuses me, if I change out g with f then integrate(h,0,A) is fine. Where am I missing something?

Comment: f _does_ accept an array of values - try it!  `f(1:3)` - so it works with `integrate` without change. `g` does not accept an array of values because `integrate` does not accept an array of values for the limits of integration. Therefore, h does not accept an array of value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `?integrate`

`integrate(f, lower, upper)`

- f should be a function taking a numeric and returning a numeric
  your `f <- function(a) a^2` is ok.
- the next 2 arguments should be the limits of integration ("numbers")

```
integrate(f,2,5)
39 with absolute error < 4.3e-13
(1/3) * (5^3-2^3)
39
```

the error message `length(lower) == 1 is not TRUE`
means that the second argument is not "one" number